# Fitting model with NaN values in the features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would know if there is a method for fitting a model even some features contains some NaN values.

X

```
    Feature1    Feature2    Feature3    Feature4    Feature5
0   0.1         NaN         0.3         NaN         4.0
1   4.0         6.0         6.6         99.0        2.0
2   11.0        15.0        2.2         3.3         NaN
3   1.0         6.0         2.0         2.5         4.0
4   5.0         11.2        NaN         3.0         NaN
```

Code

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Answer (score 3):

Usually, tree-based classifiers can handle `NaNs` as they just split the dataset based on the feature values. Of course, it also depends on how the algorithm is implemented.

I am not sure about sklearn but if you really want to classify them while preserving the `NaN` values, your best choice is to use `XGBoost`. It is not on sklearn but there are very good libraries and they are easy to use as well. It is also one of the most powerful classifiers, so you should definitely try it!
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SimpleImputer()` to replace `nan` by the mean value, or a constant prior to fitting the model. Have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) to find the correct strategy that work for your usecase.

In your case if you want to have still have `nan` value and take them out of the equation, you can simply replace `nan` by `0` using `SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0)`

As follows:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0),
    LinearRegression()
)
model.fit(X, y)
```

**Note:** I am using here a pipeline to all the steps in one go.

Comment: I don't want get rid of them, I want to preserve NaN values.

Comment: What's the point of preserving NaNs ? @luka

Comment: I would fit a model with certain features that I have and do not approximate a value, for example a mean of other features, or get rid of them.

Comment: @luka, I edited my answer. By setting the `nan` value to `0` you will take them out of the equation without getting rid of them.

Comment: @AntoineDubuis But in this way the model will consider `0` as value? Indeed the value of those features is not `0`

Comment: Well, if you want to solve your problem using a model such as `LinearRegression` then this is the best way to do it.

Comment: if there are other features which can be 0 as well, setting the nans to 0 will avoid model from distinguishing a nan from a feature being really 0. If you impute nans with this logic, it has to a unique number that other feature can not have. -1 maybe or so